# Return association object created by update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

`QuestionList` has many `Question`.

I'm creating a `question` in the controller by the `update` method:

```
@question_list.update(params.require(:question_list).permit(questions_attributes: [:id, :question_list_id, :title, :position, :_destroy]))
```

How would I return the created object?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, the [`update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update) method already returns the updated object doesn't it?

Comment: @vee No it returns a boolean value for me. But you're right that the docs says it should return an object.

Comment: @BradWerth How come I get `true` as value (for `q`) when doing `q = Question.last.update(title: "Just testing")`?

Comment: The docs are right, it returns the object. `Person.update` returns an object, `@person.update` returns bool.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update

Comment: @Iceman Any idea how to return a created associated object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Why are you using update to create an object. You should be adding a new Question to the QuestionList, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@new_question = Question.create(question_params) 
@question_list.questions << @new_question
```

Also you should define your parameters in a (private) controller method

```
def question_params
  params.require(:question_list).permit(questions_attributes: [:id, :question_list_id, :title, :position, :_destroy])
end
```